# Retrieve Mysql Stored Procedure Data Using Entity Framework 5

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5

I am using Mysql with Entity Framework 5. But using Entity Framework to execute a store procedure  I am not getting any data.

I've tried these ways:

1) Adding stored procedure to my edmx then execute that as a function.

```
var returnedData = db.MyStoredProcedureName(); // here db is the context
```

2) By following way:

```
var returnedData = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("MyStoredProcedureName"); // here db is the context
```

Both times I am getting 0 (zero) as output.

But the stored procure is supposed to return all data of a table ('select * from myTable').

Comment: Have you solved this issue ? I am having the same issue. Please post answer if you have work around this issue.